# jQuery Validator - Override validation message for a boolean response from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using `jQuery Validator` in order to process a simple form. Everything works as it should, but I would like to modify a little bit the validation process. I have integrated a small `Ajax` request to test whether the entered email already exists in the DB. The response is `1` in case the email already exists or `0` otherwise. I noticed that a `label` tag is created under the `input` field in case the email is not valid:

```
<label id="email-error" class="error" for="email">This field is required.</label>
```

**Is it possible** to override this generated label (after the `jQuery Validator` has validated that the provided email is valid), to indicate whether this email exists in the DB or not?
Suppose, for `1` the generated `label` will look like this:

```
<label id="email-error" class="error" for="email">This Email is already in use.</label>
```

This is the current configuration of the validator:

```
var $validator=$("#form-register").validate({
rules:{
     email:{
     required: true
     }
  }
});
```

This is the HTML form:

```
<form id="form-register" class="p-t-15" role="form">
   <div class="form-group form-group-default" id="email_div">
      <label>What's your email address?</label>
      <div>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">      
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I am definitely sure that there should be a `remote` option for this!

Comment: You would not need to mess with the error message for `required`.... you would...  1. Use the `remote` method or 2. Use the `addMethod()` method to write your own rule.  I recommend #1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`remote`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method) option here:

```
$( "#form-register" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: "check-email.php"
    }
  }
});
```

> Makes the email field required, an email and does a remote request to check if the given address is already taken. In addition, the http method is set to "post" and the username is sent alongside the email address.

```
$( "#form-register" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "check-email.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          email: function() {
            return $( "#email" ).val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```